# how to combine regular FormValue with multipart form data in Golang net/http Request

Tags: http, go, multipartform-data

I want to call `FormValue` on `golang` `net/http` `Request` from several  middleware handler functions before serving the request. And I do not want to invalidate the request while doing this.

It works fine except when the incoming request has a `multipart` `form-data`, the data gets invalidated after I call `FormValue` and there is nothing to parse in the final route.

Comment: Can you be more specific than "data gets invalidated"?   What error are you seeing?  Subsequent calls return `""` or some sort of panic... or?

Comment: From the docs:  "FormValue calls ParseMultipartForm and ParseForm if necessary"... and "After one call to ParseMultipartForm, subsequent calls have no effect.".  `FormValue()` may be intrinsically non-repeatable (which would sound like a bug to me!).    Is there a simple example to test?

Comment: the content is nil.

Answer (score 4):

I wrote a utility function that solved my problem:

```
package utils

import (
    "bytes"
    "io"
    "io/ioutil"
    "mime"
    "mime/multipart"
    "net/http"
    "strings"
)

// Get form values without invalidating the request body in case the data is multiform
func GetFormValues(request *http.Request, keys []string) []string {
    var values []string
    mediaType, params, err := mime.ParseMediaType(request.Header.Get("Content-Type"))
    if err != nil || !strings.HasPrefix(mediaType, "multipart/") {
        for i := range keys {
            values = append(values, request.FormValue(keys[i]))
        }
    } else { // multi form
        buf, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(request.Body)
        origBody := ioutil.NopCloser(bytes.NewBuffer(buf))
        var rdr = multipart.NewReader(bytes.NewBuffer(buf), params["boundary"])
        for len(values) < len(keys) {
            part, err_part := rdr.NextPart()
            if err_part == io.EOF {
                break
            }
            for i := range keys {
                if part.FormName() == keys[i] {
                    buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
                    buf.ReadFrom(part)
                    values = append(values, buf.String())
                }
            }
        }
        request.Body = origBody
    }
    if len(values) == len(keys) {
        return values
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}

// Get form value without invalidating the request body in case the data is multiform
func GetFormValue(request *http.Request, key string) string {
    if result := GetFormValues(request, []string{key}); len(result) == 1 {
        return result[0]
    } else {
        return ""
    }
}
```

Now instead of calling

```
value := request.FormValue(key)
```

I do

```
value := utils.GetFormValue(request, key)
```

or for multiple values

```
values := utils.GetFormValues(request, []string{keys...})
```

Comment: Cool!   Should this maybe be a bug / rfe on https://github.com/golang/go/issues?  (It looks like the current behavior was the result of fixing a bug that was causing a /segfault/ in this use case!)

Comment: I agree this should be a bug, I think it is very intuitive to expect the request body to be nil after calling `FormValue` function.